# Adding JavaScript variables into local scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a set of variables that I'd like to take as input to a function, then define them for use within that function.

For example:

```
var variables = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
};

function doSomething (scope) {
    makeLocal(scope); // I'd like something to do this

    return foo + bar;
}

doSomething(variables); // should return 3
```

Does such a thing exist? PHP has a facility to do this called [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), I'm hoping a similar thing exists for JavaScript. I know that I can add attributes to `window`, but I'd prefer not to pollute my global namespace if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with `scope.foo + scope.bar`?

Comment: @entropic I plan for there to be a lot of variables, and for them to be used a lot. I'd rather not have "scope" (or even a one-character variable name) everywhere if I can help it

Comment: There's not a native metod for this in JS. If this could be done using some ugly `eval()` trick, you'd have to do it in `doSomething()`, otherwise new variables would be in the scope of `makeLocal()`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have any equivalant of PHP's extract. One way to get something close would be to bind the current context when calling `makeLocal()` and assign the variables to that:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XH2b6/)

```
var variables = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
};

function makeLocal(scope){
    for(var key in scope){
        this[key] = scope[key];   
    }
}

function doSomething (scope) {
    makeLocal.call(this, scope);

    return foo + bar;
}
```

The downside to this is if `doSomething()` has no context, it will be the global object (window in browsers) and your variables would pollute the global scope.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, this does not appear to work in any context other than `window`. Can you provide an example of it working in another context?

Comment: This will only work when `this` is the global context (`window` most of the time, except e.g. in strict mode). Will not work when `doSomething.call({}, scope)` or `obj.doSomething(scope)` for that matter; you'd need to use `return this.foo + this.bar;`. But when it works, it will pollute the global namespace, of course.

Comment: Yeah agreed - it doesn't work outside the global scope. The only way to get it to work in any scope would be to make it store `window[key] = scope[key]` instead of `this`, but that's always using globals. I don't believe there is any other way to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good javascript library that allow you to use php functions, just like [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Have a look !

http://phpjs.org

Here is what you're looking for:

http://phpjs.org/functions/extract/